# Python Willie Bot- Running a function after channel join

Tags: python, bots, irc

If anyone is familiar with Willie, I'm trying to get him to say something immediately after joining a channel, but only one time (so the interval module will not help here).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

IRC sends a JOIN message back to you when you've joined a channel, so you can do something like this:

```
@event('JOIN')
@rule('.*')
def say_hi(bot, trigger):
    bot.msg(trigger.sender, 'Hi!')
```